# How to find the cost of stored procedures before executing in big query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I wanted to know the data processed by a stored procedure before executing it in bigquery?
Whenever I build and call a sored procedure in bigquery, It says "WARNING: Could not compute bytes processed estimate for script"

How can someone knows how much data he's going to process also if stored procedure get failed, still data will be processed and cost is involved there?